# SPRING 3.0 MVC 2 page 1 controller

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I just want to have `2 functions` in `JAVA Spring 3.0 MVC` like `page1.htm` and `page2.htm` and just 1 controller, kinda is in `CodeIgniter`, i don't know why is so hard ...

This is what i did till now

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package controllers;

import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;

// Import models
import models.LoginModel;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 *
 * @author Candy
 */

@RequestMapping("/app")
public class LoginController extends SimpleFormController {
    public LoginController()
    {
        //Initialize controller properties here or 
        //in the Web Application Context

        setCommandClass(models.Employee.class);
        setCommandName("Employee");
        //setSuccessView("pages/login/login_form_view");
        //setFormView("pages/login/login_execute_view");
    }


    // On form load
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception 
    {
        LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel(request);

        if(!loginModel.isLogged())
        {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("pages/login/login_form_view");

            // mv.addObject("chestie",loginModel.isLogged());

            return mv;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/dashboard.htm");
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void doSubmitAction(Object command) throws Exception
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    //Use onSubmit instead of doSubmitAction 
    //when you need access to the Request, Response, or BindException objects
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(
    HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response, 
    Object command, 
    BindException errors) throws Exception 
    {
        // User has submited a POST request
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("pages/login/login_execute_view");

        // Check if the user is logged or not, user must be NOT LOGGED in order to log
        LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel(request);
        if(!loginModel.isLogged())
        {
            // Just continue
            String email = request.getParameter("email").toString();
            String password = request.getParameter("password").toString();

            // Check this email/pass
            Map<String,String> resultLogin = loginModel.login(email, password);

            String result = resultLogin.get("result").toString();
            String reason = resultLogin.get("reason").toString();
            // String qqq = resultLogin.get("qqq").toString();

            /*
            java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();

            java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
                 new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);
            */
            if(result == "true")
            {
                // Login is good, redirect to dashboard
                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/dashboard.htm");

                // Display the error
                //mv.addObject("loginResult",result);
                //mv.addObject("loginReason",reason);
                //mv.addObject("qqq",qqq);
                //mv.addObject("qqq2",request.getSession().getAttribute("is_logged").toString());
            }
            else
            {
                // Display the error
                mv.addObject("loginResult",result);
                mv.addObject("loginReason",reason);

                return mv;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/login.htm");
        }
    }     
}
```

this controller will not work if I remove

```
applicationContext.xml
<bean class="controllers.LoginController"/>

dispatcher-servlet.xml
<bean class="controllers.LoginController" p:formView="pages/login/login_form_view" p:successView="pages/login/login_execute_view"/>

web.xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.LoginController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

1. Why i have to edit 3 XML when i create a new controller? Is not a simpler way?
2. All i want right now is just make another function `logout()` that loads the `ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("pages/login/logout_view");`, that's all.

And this

```
@RequestMapping("/app")
@Override
protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception 
{
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("pages/login/login_form_view");

    return mv;
}
```

gives me 404 error ...

1. What should i use? `SimpleFormController`, `extend Controller`, `AbstractController` (i'm using `NETBEANS`). I'm confused, i wish there were a good java framework like `CodeIgniter`. I don't quite understand how mappings work, but i do know how an `apache rewrite` works.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You've got Spring 3.0, so consider using annotation based `@Controller` controllers.

Comment: can you give me an example? like a link/video? i'm confused about this framework ....

Comment: There are so many resources out there. Just look it up.

Comment: And `result == "true"` -> Don't do that.

Comment: @Rohit Jain => i'm obsessed with associative arrays from PHP like `if($result_function['result'] == 'true') then ... do stuff` ... that's why ...

@SotiriosDelimanolis trust me i have searched, it is not like `PHP` or `ASP` where everything seems logical and clear, i'm getting stuck at basic things .... and trust me that i worked with web technologies before ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring 3, you can easily use `@controller` annotation for your controller class which are used for your page request and navigation.

You can use `@Service` annotation for your business logic and `@Repository` for your Database transaction and bind these layers together using `@Autowired` annotation as well .

so your request goes this way ( `UI Request` -> `@Controller` -> `@Service` -> `@Repository` ) and come back to the original controller class again for navigation.

But about your question, when you mark a class with `@Controller` annotation in spring, that simply means you candidate that class for your URL mappings and navigations, the sample below show how you can use `@RequestMapping` annotation inside Controlller Class for your URL mapping:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class Employees{

@AutoWired
private EmployeeServiceInterface empServInt;

  @ModelAttribute("empAdd")
  public Employee createEmployeeModel(){
      return new Employee();
  } 

  @RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("empAdd")Employee employee,Model model, HttpSesion session){

     Employee employee = empServInt.createUser(employee);
     if(yourCondition()){
          return "redirect:/TO_THIS_PAGE";
      }
    return "GO_TO_PAGE_NAVIGATION_HERE";
  }
}
```

note that @RequestMapping get activated when a request come with the URL `HOST_NAME:PORT/PROJECT_NAME/employee/add` because of `@RequesMapping` annotation value.

Secondly `@ModelAttribute` you saw in sample create a model for your page that helps you to submit the Employee Object Bean values from UI using commandName attribute in Spring Form tag which binds the html inputs to Employee Bean class by using `path=""` attribute :

```
<form:form commandName="empAdd" method="post" >...</form:form>
```

Thirdly take note that the @AutoWired can automatically wired an interface to an implementation so in my example if a class like EmployeeServiceImpl implements the interface `EmployeeServiceInterface` by calling the interface methods like: `empServInt.createUser(employee);` spring automatically call related EmployeeServiceImpl.createUser(employee) implementation method for you.

Fourthly: take note that for you to be able to use Controller and the Service & Repository annotation to work you should have defined the packages that have those annotations in your Spring Descriptor XML file like so:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="java.package" />
```

Fifthly if you noticed the method inside Employees has String return type that provide your navigation but for this to work you should have define the page prefix and suffix that is going to return inside your Spring Descriptor XMl file as well like so:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

according to above config, if your method which is annotated with @RequestMapping is returning `employee` String, Spring go and fetch the page from this location:

> [PREFIX]employee[POSSIX] -->  /WEB-INF/view/employee.jsp

For better understanding I found a useful sample link for you. [Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm)

Good Luck !

Comment: Thank you very much, but is not like i am not capable to understand, but for me java web seems weird, can you look on my project please? i got stuck on this, please. I made it in NETBEANS. And as you can see, i tried, but nothning, not even the simple pages ==>> https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/6b9c8d4ffe5119a10a85187bfae3dbc520140204225053/d5e4bb9036b03772b9507e22ac6a547420140204225053/fecd22  THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH!